# Java Eclipse James Import Maven Projects maven-bundle-plugin No marketplace entries found

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, james

I attempted to import all of the Apache James email server projects.  The result is no 'next' button is enabled.  No market place for maven-bundle-plugin is found, etc.  Thanks for help.

Comment: I also have a screen shot of of the result, but can't upload it.

Comment: Really using Maven 2? Have you installed m2e in Eclipse? Which Eclipse version do you use?

Comment: The eclipse version is 4.2.  I have resolved this issue but it was pesky until I added the solution to the pom files.

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html

Comment: Maven 2 is EoL http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html, http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-announce/201503.mbox/%3C20150320213920.6AE4B17423%40minotaur.apache.org%3E

Comment: I see, thanks.  Well, I installed m2 about two years ago.  I suppose I should update it.